# How to create collectionView app with (items->items->detail) style

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

For example, this picture shows how the collection View should look like.

[image: picture]

I want the First View to show an array of around 6 items in collection view.
2nd View to show an array of objects that relate to the object you click in first view. Which are 50+ objects depending on which object was clicked. For 3rd View is going to be a pop up view of detailed info for the object you clicked in 2nd View.

I know how to fill a collection view but not how to create what I want. Just want a collection view like in the picture, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your collectionViewControllers you can override this method and pass some data to your destination controllers

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

Comment: okay thats to prepare but how would I have the data connect with each other? if a user clicks an item in an array, how can I get detailed info related to that item to show? I can't use another array because thats several separate items not a detailed list for each item.

Comment: This post should illustrate things better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173734/how-do-i-use-prepareforsegue-in-swift